# MVC Routing problem, 404 and unmatched routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to setup a routing scheme in MVC3 that matches against a legacy (SP 2007) system. These are the routes I've setup:

```
routes.MapRoute("administration", 
    "Administration/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Administration", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("workOrderSearch", 
    "WorkOrderSearch", 
    new {controller = "Home", action = "WorkOrderSearch"});
routes.MapRoute("customers",
    "{customerNumber}/{action}", 
    new {controller = "customer", action = "Index"}, 
    new {customerNumber = @"\d*"});
routes.MapRoute("graphicNames",
    "{customerNumber}/{graphicNameId}/{action}/{id}", 
    new {controller="GraphicName", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional}, 
    new {customerNumber = @"\d*",graphicNameId = @"\d*", action=@"\w*"});
routes.MapRoute("workOrders", 
    "{customerNumber}/{graphicNameId}/{graphicNumber}/WorkOrder/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "WorkOrder", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
    new { graphicNameId = @"\d*", graphicNumber = @"\d*-\d*" });
routes.MapRoute("graphics", 
    "{customerNumber}/{graphicNameId}/{graphicNumber}/{action}", 
    new { controller = "Graphic", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
    new { graphicNameId = @"\d*", graphicNumber = @"\d*-\d*" });

routes.MapRoute("Default", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

It mostly works just fine. However, when trying to hit the "graphicNames" route, I run into a problem. If I use this url:

http://localhost:1234/1234/321/Index

it works fine and I get to the Index action on the GraphicName controller. However, if I do this:

http://localhost:1234/1234/321

I get a 404.

All other routes appear to work as expected.

Edit: The solution was to add a constraint to the customer's route so that actions were only 'action=@"[A-Za-z]*"

Comment: add a trailing slash to the request.. does it work?

Comment: No, a trailing slash at the end has not helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above you have:

```
routes.MapRoute("graphicNames",
"{customerNumber}/{graphicNameId}/{action}/{id}", 
new {controller="GraphicName", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional}, 
new {customerNumber = @"\d*",graphicNameId = @"\d*", action=@"\w*"});
```

however before that you have

```
routes.MapRoute("customers",
"{customerNumber}/{action}", 
new {controller = "customer", action = "Index"}, 
new {customerNumber = @"\d*"});
```

which based on your url with only TWO parameters
/1234/321
will match the customers route first. Either add a route constraint that action must be alpha only, or move this beneath your graphicNames route, since order is *very* important in route matching.

Comment: I don't see how I have two optional parameters. Action has a default and id is optional. Are you saying that customerNumber and graphicNameId are somehow optional?

Comment: doh. late night. I think I should say "missing" not optional. I believe the parser is having an issue matching parameters up. Try to specify a default for graphicNameId=0 or graphicNameId="" and see if anything changes.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: edited above - I think your customer route is matching this syntax., you have two parameters only and I think it believes your "321" is your customer route "Action" parameter. You need to move that route down underneath the other one or specify it must be alpha only in a route constraint.

Comment: Good catch! I had actually added a constraint on the customer's action, but I had stupidly used "\w*", which would still be matching against "123". I added this: action=@"[A-Za-z]*"    and all seems well. Thanks!